# XPS export from WPF - only one image is exported

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, xps

I want to export the content from WPF app (C#,MVVM) to XPS.
I have a bunch of objects and every object contains an image (type=BitmapFrame), which is displayed using **source** property:

```html
<Image Source="{Binding BusinessUnit.Picture}" />
```

All those objects are placed on a control called GraphCanvas. Every picture is loaded and it is properly displayed on a screen.

When using the export code:

```cs
            using (var package = Package.Open(saveFileDialog.FileName, FileMode.Create))
            {
                var xpsDocument = new XpsDocument(package);

                var writer = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(xpsDocument);

                writer.Write(GraphCanvas.ExportCanvas);

                xpsDocument.Close();
            }
```

everything is exported properly except of images. Only one image is exported (and it's available in resources folder when browsing through XPS structure) and this one image is used as a substitution for every other image that should be exported.

What might be a reason that all the other images are not exported?

Comment: Did you look at what GraphCanvas.ExportCanvas gives you to see if it has all the images?

Answer (score 0):

I've faced similar issue when printing multiple pages, and eventually I had to iterate on each Item in page and do this:

```
fwElement.Arrange(new Rect(new Size(fwElement.ActualWidth, fwElement.ActualHeight)));
```

Since you have only single element, this might work for you:

```
GraphCanvas.ExportCanvas.Measure(GraphCanvas.ExportCanvas.RenderSize);
GraphCanvas.ExportCanvas.Arrange(new Rect(new Size(GraphCanvas.ExportCanvas.ActualWidth, GraphCanvas.ExportCanvas.ActualHeight)));
writer.Write(GraphCanvas.ExportCanvas);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but I had the same issue in my WPF MVVM (I'm using DevExpress MVVM) app, and my resolution may help others in the future.

I had a page of several images, and when printing the 1st image on the page replaced all the other images! I'm not sure why it did this.

Each of my image UI controls was bound to a byte array, and the images displayed perfectly in the app. I resolved the print issue by converting my byte arrays to a BitmapImage to which each image UI control was bound.  All images print correctly now.

My View XAML:

```
    <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding Bitmap[0]}" />
    <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Source="{Binding Bitmap[1]}" />
    <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Source="{Binding Bitmap[2]}" />
    <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Source="{Binding Bitmap[3]}" />
```

My ViewModel bound properties:

```
    private List<BitmapImage> bitmap;

    public virtual List<BitmapImage> Bitmap
    {
        get { return bitmap; }
        set { bitmap= value; }
    }
```

My code for printing each child view in a TabControl (some tabs contained other UI objects other than images):

```
    public void PrintDocument(TabControl control)
    {
        PrintDocumentImageableArea area = null;
        XpsDocumentWriter dw = PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(ref area);
        SerializerWriterCollator c = dw.CreateVisualsCollator();

        foreach (var tabitem in ((TabControl)control).Items)
        {
            UIElement childVisual1 = (UIElement)((TabItem)tabitem).Content;
            var outputSize = new Size(area.MediaSizeHeight, area.MediaSizeWidth);

            ((UIElement)childVisual1).Measure(outputSize);
            ((UIElement)childVisual1).Arrange(new Rect(outputSize));
            ((UIElement)childVisual1).UpdateLayout();

            if (c != null) c.Write(childVisual1);
        }

        if (c != null) c.EndBatchWrite();
    }
```

This [article](https://www.abhishekshukla.com/wpf/advanced-wpf-part-2-printing-in-windows-presentation-foundation/) helped with WPF printing with XPS